# Translation of 愿你出走多年，归来还是少年

Tags: translation, meaning

I came across this phrase. I am curious to understand it.

愿你出走多年，归来还是少年

When I translate it using a variety of online tools, I come up with something like

"you would like to run for many years and return as a teenager."

Is that an accurate description/translation of what this phrase means in English? Or is there some other meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition is the literal meaning of the phrase.

It comes from the book 《愿你出走半生，归来仍是少年》

The actual meaning of it is no matter what happens to you and no matter how many places you have been, you should always keep a beginner's heart.

Answer (score 1):

This link 
http://www.zybang.com/question/cf6f5a8be999c03ebea19cce043813bb.html

has this answer:

希望你不管在人世上经过多少世事 再见时仍能保留少年人所有的赤子之心.

Which I translate as:

I hope, no matter what you experience in this world, that when we meet again, you can still retain the purity and innocence of youth.